# How can I get access to a class backed resource dictionary instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I've got a resource dictionary with several control defined in it (TextBox and Button) that are unrelated to each other. I can access the controls via TryFindResource without problems.

Next, I wanted to attach an event to the button, so I added x:Class to the dictionary and created a backing class (based on info I found here) and the event functions correctly.

What I'm having problems with is: how do I gain access to the created resource directory (i.e. my class) that backs the load xaml?  Ultimately I want to create a number of complicated controls in the resource directory and have a simple, single function I can call in the backing class to give me the list of those controls back, so I can add them to my window, rather than needing call to TryFindResource for each control.

I have a constructor in the class (and have a call to InitializeComponent), but the auto created internal fields that represent the TextBox and Button are null. The constructor is called early (well before anything in my GUI) but the behind-the-scenese Connect call apparently hasn't been done even by the time my window's Loaded event is called.

I've done a ton of searching but everything I've found stops at the defining the class point and doesn't show any usage after that.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something about how this all functions and what it's capable of, but it really seems like I should be able to get an instance somehow.

Partial XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MM.Window.TitleBarControls"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <MMM:ApplicationInformation x:Key="ApplicationInformation" />

    <Button x:Key="ButtonTest"
            x:Name="ButtonTest"
            Content="Button"
            Click="ButtonClickTest" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Partial class:

```
    public partial class TitleBarControls : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public ObservableList<object> HeaderControls = new();

        public TitleBarControls()
        {
            TitleBarControlsMain = this;

            InitializeComponent();

            // ButtonTest is null here
            HeaderControls.Add(ButtonTest);
        }

        private void ButtonClickTest(object sender_, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e_)
        {
            int i = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "give me the list of those controls back, so I can add them to my window" - why go to such troubles for smth as simple as adding controls to window??

Comment: The controls are going in a base window class that I inherit from later, so it has no backing xaml. If I understand it correctly WPF has no visual inheritance (and if I'm wrong please tell me, because that's a huge limitation IMO)

Comment: I should maybe clarify that my base window is inherited from DevExpress ThemedWindow and my goal is to add control to the title bar that are available on all of my applications in an extensible fashion. I can do it already, but the boilerplate code is a waste.

Comment: Can you make a WPF User Control that has all your controls on it already? Create a new instance of your User Control then add that in onto your inherited form as needed.

Comment: @Byrd Maybe. Not want I want to do, but on the surface that seems like it will work

Comment: if you have a single instance of Button (`<Button x:Key="ButtonTest"` in resource dictionary), you can display it one place exactly. it won't work with multiple windows. create style for title bar button, put style into RD, and apply it to any button in any window

Comment: @ASh I'm not looking to put it in more than one window, the controls will only ever be on the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button in your example is a *resource* that gets added to the `ResourceDictionary` itself.

Remove the `x:Name` (to avoid confusion) from the XAML markup and access it using the indexer in the code-behind:

```
HeaderControls.Add(this["ButtonTest"]);
```